# Abrir link em outra aba quando clicar botão

Tags: javascript, html

Eu já sei fazer abrir em outra janela, quero quando eu fechar ela, atualizar meu site!

Código dela é esse:

```
<a href="https://www.blogger.com/blogger.g?blogID=811315793714916374#" onclick="window.open('http://bit.ly/loga-se','pagename','resizable,height=260,width=370'); return false;" style="font-size: xx-large;" target="_blank"><img border="0" src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-K_dSSmrPEjI/V_ZrScV1fdI/AAAAAAAAA_U/gJyCpyJT47c4Y4dYkB99_I_sxf4_X2q_gCLcB/s1600/bt.PNG" /></a>
```

[image: quando fechar essa janela atualizar meu site!]

Comment: Não sei qual seu proposito abrindo uma nova janela, mas seria muito mais pratico se você mostra-se o conteúdo em um modal, pois a partir dele fica mais fácil atribuir ações para a sua pagina que o originou.

Answer (score -1):

Olá, talvez o que você queira seja o atributo `window.close()`

Esse atributo atualizará uma página descrita toda vez que você fecha a página pelo botão.

veja se isso resolve:

```js
onclick="window.open('http://bit.ly/loga-se','pagename','resizable,height=260,width=370'); return false; window.close(https://www.blogger.com/blogger.g?blogID=811315793714916374#)"
```

Espero que te ajude!

Comment: aonde que eu coloco esse codigo?

Answer (score -1):

Veja se isso resolve !

```
<a href="https://www.blogger.com/blogger.g?blogID=811315793714916374#" class="link" style="font-size: xx-large;">
    <img border="0" src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-K_dSSmrPEjI/V_ZrScV1fdI/AAAAAAAAA_U/gJyCpyJT47c4Y4dYkB99_I_sxf4_X2q_gCLcB/s1600/bt.PNG" />
</a>

<script>

document.querySelector('.link').addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var win = window.open('http://google.com', 'pagename', 'resizable,height=260,width=370');
    var popupTick = setInterval(function() {
        if (win.closed) {
            clearInterval(popupTick);
            console.log('window closed!');
            // window.location.reload(true);
        }
    }, 500);
    return false;
});

</script>
```